# What size Baader solar filter do I need and how do I use it on my Nikon D5300?

Tags: nikon, filters, sun, eclipse

I've been trying to make sure I get the right solar filter for the upcoming eclipse in the US in August, but I'm inexperienced so I wanted to ask if the filter I'm looking at is correct. The one I found is [a Baader filter](http://astrosolar.com/en/products/whitelight/assf-baader-solar-filter-for-spotting-scope-amateur-telescopes-and-camera-lenses/). I'm going to use a zoom lens on my Nikon D5300 (no telescope or spotting scope). The only issue I can see is the size: they only have 50 and 65 mm, and my lens is 55mm. Is this the correct filter? If so, how do I deal with the size?

Comment: What lens are you using? That seller's page has [a tool](http://astrosolar.com/baader-solar-filter/index.php?lang=en) that specifies which filter you need to fit specific lenses.

Comment: @Anthony C 55mm focal length? 55mm filter size? Or 55mm width across the front of the lens (including barrel)?

Answer (score 1):

That filter seems to have a weird mounting mechanism. The screws might scratch the lens exterior. Perhaps something like [this Mr Seymour 55mm screw-on filter (Amazon link)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01LOM2WBM) would be a better option. I'm assuming your lens's filter diameter is 55mm.

Comment: Thank you - that does look better. Are there any other companies that are good for this type of filter?

Comment: The bolts have a rubber coating to prevent scratching the instrument to which the filter is attached.

Comment: I'm not sure about this type of filter but Hoya filters are quite popular amongst the photographing community.

Comment: I guess the main thing I'm wondering is how you can tell if a filter is good quality - I haven't bought any of these before, and I really would like to avoid frying my camera sensor by accident. Is there any way to tell if a filter is up to par, or do you just have to take the company's word for it?

Comment: Every decent filter company publishes data on its filters though I don't know how to read it and make sense of it. My dad was a photography enthusiast and he always used Hoya filters on his Pentax film SLR. I guess I never questioned his choice and now my Nikon almost exclusively uses Hoya.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you just buy some Baader sheet material from the same vendor, and [make your own filter holder.](http://astrosolar.com/en/information/how-to/how-to-make-an-inexpensive-filter-cell/) The reason being, Baader film is thin and somewhat fragile. If you perforate it or stretch it, you run the risk of the filter no longer performing its job (i.e., letting in too much light). You can make several films for your camera from a single roll, and have some ready to practice solar photography with, or apply to binoculars, etc.